# Can javascript autoplay an HTML5 video on android (built in autoplay does not work)

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to autoplay a video on page load, and the built in 'autoplay' feature doe snot work on android (which I have found well documented in these forums)

However I have not been anble to find if there is a possible javascript solution to force the video to autoplay and loop on page load.

My device is a Samsung galaxy Tab 2 – version 4.0.4

Is this possible?

Here is my video code:

```
  <video  id="video1" width="430" height="430" controls  preload="auto" poster="990643607_AN.jpg">
  <source src="990643607_AN.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="990643607_AN.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="990643607_AN.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <object width="430" height="430" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
          <param name="movie" value="../mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" />
          <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=990643607_AN.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </object>
  </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<video  id="video1" width="430" height="430" controls  preload="true" poster="990643607_AN.jpg">
  <source src="990643607_AN.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="990643607_AN.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="990643607_AN.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <object width="430" height="430" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
          <param name="movie" value="../mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" />
          <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=990643607_AN.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </object>
  </video>

function callback () {
    document.querySelector('video').play();
}

window.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
```

Try this code

Comment: I set it up and it seemed to set the video in a paused state: <script>
function callback () {
    document.querySelector('video').play();
}

window.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
</script>